# Workaround for Injecting a service into an abstract class to be available in subclasses - asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Update**
Well, I wasn't sure what I was asking for so it got a bit of an XY-question/discussion.

Main problem now is that I have an abstract base class which can be seen as a service, and sub services that derives from it (properties / abstract methods).

I've tried workarounds with using Interface, but no luck. I do not need the IOtherService in my Controller, so I don't want to inject it there.

Startup:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyBaseService, MyBaseService>();
```

Base service:

```
public MyBaseService(IOtherService other)
   {

       OtherService = other;
    }

public MyBaseService()
{
    // this runs
}
```

Derived service

```
public class DerivedService : MyBaseService
{
    public DerivedService(string x)
    {
    }

    public DoStuff()
    {
        OtherService.RunSomething(); 
    }
}
```

I just need IOtherService to be injected in my Base service so my child "services" can use it from an inherited property.

Or is this an example of property injection?

Comment: If you add the Interface to Vehicle without giving code, all inheritors either have to provide code for it - or be a abstract class themself. For inheritance, Interfaces work very much like abstract functions. Either you code them out, or you have to stay abstract.

Comment: @Christopher Yes I was thinking about it, and I think it's a bit bad. I will update the question

Comment: Well. You want to inject dependencies right into an entity model? That's a massive anti-pattern.

Comment: @VRoxa Ah, well.. No ´Car´ is not an entity model, it's more of a self sustained part of the whole application, so it has functions etc. I should update my question to be more clear

Comment: Microsoft's MS.DI container does not support property injection, so you will need to pass the dependency through all constructors like `public Vehicle(IDep...)` `public Car(IDep dep):base(dep)`. You can try other DI container like [`Autofac`](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html)

Comment: @GuruStron Can I not get it from `IServiceProvider ` somehow ?

Comment: @BakedInhalf I think you did something wrong. If Car is a model it shouldn't have any functionality. if it has a functionality so it's a kind of service, so should be added in `ServiceCollection` thus `VehicleCleaner` can inject directly in it!

Comment: @BakedInhalf If you register your `Car` or `Vehicle` to the DI container, the `IServiceProvider` will take the responsability to feed up their dependencies.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour Yes it has functionallity... kind of a service, but there are 5+ of them, all using the same abstract base class ´Vehicle´

Comment: @BakedInhalf you can inject it via ctor =)))

Comment: @BakedInhalf If they are services and they depend on other services, then they must be registered to the DI container. Maybe as themselves, maybe as their parent class `Vehicle`. Just depends on your application policies.

Comment: @VRoxa Ok so registrating just ´Vehicle´ could do the trick? `services.AddScoped<Vehicle>();` ?

Comment: @BakedInhalf This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) related to design issue. It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: No, if you want to inject a `Car` to another service, then you must register a `Car`. I just mentioned that you could narrow the implementation of the `Car` by injecting a `Vehicle`.

Comment: @Nkosi I wish, but it's massive. It's an API, and each child is a sub-process that connects to other API's, but they all share some properties and methods from the parent. I was hoping my example code would provide an understanding of my problem.

Comment: @BakedInhalf you can reduce the hassle via introducing `VehicleBaseParams` class which will be registered in DI and have all needed base deps. Still you will need to pass it trough whole hierarchy as I wrote before.

Comment: @Nkosi I rewrote the whole question, what it boils down to after discussion.

Answer (score 1):

**Base class:**

```
public abstract class Vehicle : ICleanVehicle
{
   private readonly ICleanVehicle _cleanVehicle;

   public Vehicle(ICleanVehicle cleanVehicle)
   {
      if (cleanVehicle == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cleanVehicle");
      _cleanVehicle = cleanVehicle;
   }
}
```

**Derived class:**

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    private readonly ICleanVehicle _cleanVehicle;

    public Car(ICleanVehicle cleanVehicle) : base(cleanVehicle)
    {
        _cleanVehicle = cleanVehicle;
    }
}
```

This way you have one single constructor defining the dependencies that the derived classes require. The derived classes will then call the constructor of the base class.

Comment: But then I would need to inject an ICleanVehicle into the controller and then as an argument to the ´Car´. Was hoping to avoid that. I just want it to appear

Comment: There is no other way of doing so. A constructor is there to instantiate a class. If you call two constructors, you'll end up with two instances.

Comment: @BakedInhalf you can register `Car` in DI so all dependencies will be resolved the. And/or introduce [`Factory`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: @GuruStron Was hoping only register the abstract base class would work.. There are so many child classes...

Comment: @BakedInhalf with some reflection magic([for example](https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-inject-all-instances-of-a-service-interface-64b37b43fdc8)) you can reduce the manual work.

Comment: @GuruStron This was similar to what i'm trying to do. Will try that out! But my hopes are still to only register the base class. I only need to inject one ore two services in each child..

Comment: @GuruStron The example site you provided got my hopes up, but now the constructor won't run. See my updated question

Comment: Well, you are missing the derived constructor call

Comment: E.g : base(cleanVehicle)